# DRY multiple if statements used to show/hide elements based on slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I'm showing and hiding 4 svg paths based on the value of a slider, all is working as expected, but it still feels a little cumbersome. Does anyone know a way to "[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)" it out a little more?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/F9Wz7/18/)

```
$('.volumeSlider').slider({
    value: 1,
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    max: 1,
    step: 0.05,
    animate: true,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        $('p').text(ui.value);
        var v = $('.volume1');
        if (ui.value == 1) {
            v.show();
        }
        if (ui.value < 1) {
            v.slice(0).hide();
            v.slice(1, 4).show();

        }
        if (ui.value <= 0.65) {
            v.slice(0, 2).hide();
            v.slice(2, 4).show();
        }
        if (ui.value <= 0.35) {
            v.slice(0, 3).hide();
            v.slice(4).show();
        }
        if (ui.value === 0) {
            v.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that the '.volume' elements are like volume indicators, the louder the sound, the more you show.

You can iterate over the '.volume' elements, compare the `index / elementCount` to `ui.value` and decide to `hide` or `show` per that comparison.

So, something like :

```
$('.volumeSlider').slider({
    value: 1,
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    max: 1,
    step: 0.05,
    animate: true,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        $('p').text(ui.value);
        var v = $('.volume1');
        for( var i = 0 ; i < v.length ; i++ ){
            ( 1-ui.value > 1 / v.length * (i + 1)) ? v.slice(i).hide() : v.slice(i).show()
        }
    }
});
```

should work. This approach will work with any number of `volume1` elements.
I did not test this, but once you see/get this I am sure you can make this work.

Further optimizations can be caching `v.length` and `1 / v.length`, you could probably also use `eq` instead of `slice()`

EDIT : I fixed the code to work with your HTML, the original was 

`( ui.value < 1 / v.length * (i + 1)) ? v.slice(i).hide() : v.slice(i).show()`
which would work if the HTML elements were created in what I see as the correct order.

Comment: This looks promising, but the paths are showing/hiding in the opposite direction and the increments have changed. http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/F9Wz7/20/

Comment: Fixed, try http://jsfiddle.net/konijn_gmail_com/2aMvf/